# Example of discontinuous function having all partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, examples-counterexamples

Is it possible to a real-valued function of two variables defined on an open set to have partial derivatives of all order and to be discontinuous at some point or maybe at each point?

Comment: In order that $\partial f/\partial x$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ be defined, $f$ would have to be continuous as a function of $x$ with $y$ fixed and vice-versa, so the discontinuity would have to happen as one approaches a point from a diagonal direction.

Comment: If the partials exist and are continuous, then the function is differentiable, hence continuous at any point in the open set.

Comment: Yes. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456581/is-there-a-discontinuous-function-on-the-plane-having-partial-derivatives-of-all

Answer (score 2):

Try $\frac {xy}{x^2 + y^2},(x,y) \ne (0,0), f(0,0) = 0$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x,y)= 2xy/ x^2+y^2$ when $x^2+y^2>0$ and $0$ when $(x,y)=0$ f is differentiable at each point of other than the origin and $D_1f(0,0)=0=D_2f(0,0)$ since $f(x,0)=0=f(0,y) \forall x,y$ but But $f(t,t)=1 \forall t\neq 0$ so f is not continuous at $0$

Comment: This post seems related to this specific example: [Sanity check on example 6.5 from “Counterexamples in probability and real analysis” by Wise and Hall](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2391016).

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3y}{x^3+y^3}$ when $(x,y)\neq 0$ and $f(0,0)=0$

Comment: The domain of this function is $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, x\ne -y\lor x=y=0\}$, which is not an open set.