# Is this map smooth?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds and
$$f:M\times N\to \mathbb{R}$$
a map. Suppose that the maps
$$M\to\mathbb{R},\quad p\mapsto f(p,q_0)$$
$$N\to\mathbb{R},\quad q\mapsto f(p_0,q)$$
are smooth for all $(p_0,q_0)\in M\times N$.

> Is $f$ smooth?
>
> **Edit:** What if $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Since this a a strictly local question, it can be reduced to the case where $M$ and $N$ are open balls in euclidean space. BTW, by "smooth", do you mean $C^\infty$?

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes "smooth" means $C^\infty$.

Comment: This looks as if it's going to become a chameleon question, so I'm going to stop answering.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks for your answer. It will not become a chameleon question. I am just wondering about continuity.

Comment: You might want to look at https://books.google.com/books?id=dULTBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA244&lpg=PA244&dq=if+a+function+on+the+plane+has+smooth+partials+of+all+orders,+is+it+smooth&source=bl&ots=s0gY7Quue2&sig=8KNpfoO00LkV3gImGrpzN5C7sfM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimv5byvdzNAhUP3GMKHVsoAYcQ6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=if%20a%20function%20on%20the%20plane%20has%20smooth%20partials%20of%20all%20orders%2C%20is%20it%20smooth&f=false which suggests that the answer might be "in that case, it's smooth," although MacLane seems to define smoothness as "all partials exist". He may have continuity as a general assumption, too.

Answer (score 1):

See [this stackexchange question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456581/is-there-a-discontinuous-function-on-the-plane-having-partial-derivatives-of-all), which gives a (negative) answer to the simplified question (i.e., on Euclidean space).

(This answer seems to have inspired the edited question in which the assumption of continuity is added, so it's no longer a complete answer, but I'm leaving it because it may prove relevant to someone else.)

Comment: Many thanks.${}$